# How many different combinations of player choices are there in Cinders?

Tags: cinders

I am playing Cinders and trying to gauge how long it will take for me to finish the game completely. I was wondering if someone could help me by telling me how many different unique combinations of decisions I could make in the game. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I am not sure how big of a game this is, but this seems like a really big list question, as there are likely multiple permutations you could go through. If that's the case, it might not work so well here as a question.

Comment: He just wants a number, not a list of all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the developers, there are 120 unique decision points in the game with a total number of choices 'over 300'.

I'm not sure what the *exact* number is so if anyone would care to count, please feel free to edit this. :P

[Source:](http://moacube.com/games/cinders/)

> The game focuses on characters and their motivations, with heavy
>   emphasis on player choices and role-playing. With 120 decision points
>   and over 300 options to choose from, Cinders allows you to shape the
>   main character’s personality and the course of the story.